# How do I remove dd-wrt from a DIR-400 router?

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I made the mistake of doing a 30/30/30 on my Dlink DIR400 and now when I access it from my browser it comes up with a page asking me for the file I want to update it with. However, none of the files I tried works. I tried putting DDwrt on it using Putty but when it reaches the load command it just sits there and i have to close the console. I can still ping my router so I am hoping that there is still life in it. Can somebody help please?

Comment: It actually sounds you have bricked your router.

Answer (score 0):

Download & install the original firmware according to the revision number on the bottom from D-LINK. - Use the same page to upload.

Once the original firmware is installed, go to dd-wrt.com for instructions to reflash.